# problems with sprites showing up on button

Tags: css, button, css-sprites, sprite, submit-button

I've tried so many things I can't figure out why the sprites aren't showing up. There are 3 states for the button: normal, hover, and active.

```
#continue_btn {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: auto;
    width: 229px;
    height: 43px;
    background-image:url(_img/continue_btn.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    float: none;
    margin-left: -23px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    border-radius: 8px;    
    }
#continue_btn a{
    background: url(_img/button_sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat -13px -11px;
    width: 229px;
    height: 43px;
}

continue_btn a:hover {
    background: url(_img/button_sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat -14px -58px;
    width: 229px;
    height: 43px;
}
continue_btn a:active {
    background: url(_img/button_sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat -14px -106px;
    width: 229px;
    height: 43px;
}
```

[You can see it here](http://www.myproduction-1.info/jquery_tools_org_css/index_closebutton.html) (click on the user input button at top left). [This is the sprite](http://www.myproduction-1.info/jquery_tools_org_css/_img/button_sprite.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you forgot leading hashes in last two declarations.

Second, in your html `#continue_btn` is input element, but in your css you define background for some nested `a` tag which doesn't (and can't, since input is not [block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Block_elements) but [inline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Inline_elements) element) exists inside your input field.

Third, I you should remove strange `0 0` declaration in `background` properties, it doesn't fit into scheme.

And fourth, `_img/button_sprite.png` points to wrong direction. Url for your case is `../_img/button_sprite.png`.

Finally, I think you need something like this:

```
#continue_btn {
    background: url(../_img/button_sprite.png) no-repeat -13px -11px;
    width: 229px;
    height: 43px;
}

#continue_btn:hover {
    background: url(../_img/button_sprite.png) no-repeat -14px -58px;
    width: 229px;
    height: 43px;
}
#continue_btn:active {
    background: url(../_img/button_sprite.png) no-repeat -14px -106px;
    width: 229px;
    height: 43px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The one last thing would be how do I get rid of the border edges which I don't believe are coming from my css. I just gave it a border-radius: 8px and that's it. I just need the border edge to be clean. Thanks again.